# react form autocomplete first name or email

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input, autocomplete

I do form in react in general nothing special.

```
    <form onSubmit={click}>
    <input
      value={firstName}
      onChange={event => inputChangedHandler(event)}
    />
       <input
      value={email}
      onChange={event => inputChangedHandler(event)}
    />
  <Button >
    send
  </Button>
</form>
```

the point it's sometimes the chrome do for me autocomplete with information of google like address and zip code etc..
and sometimes it's not.

I have some component it's the same field of input and in one it's do and in other not.

can someone explain me how it's work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a form, so you don't need that `<Button>`, Instead, specify that it's a form that will be submitted. `<input type="submit" value="send" />`
That will create a button.

> **In order to provide autocompletion, user-agents might require `<input>/<select>/<textarea>` elements to:**
>
> - Have a name and/or id attribute
> - Be descendants of a `<form>` element
> - The form to have a submit button

*MDN Autocomplete docs:
[The HTML autocomplete attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)*

Also, [the reactjs docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) show you examples that will help, like [this reactjs form codepen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/VmmPgp?editors=0010).

if you stick to the expected attributes, you'll have better luck.

Comment: thank you. in part of my input I haven't put name / id  properly.